# BarGraph in R with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a vector of word-frequency (short extract:)

```
head(goeth.sorted.freq.list,10)
goeth.text.vector
und  der  die  ihr  das  ein  was   es euch  man 

 35     24     23   20   16   15   13   12   12   12
```

which I plotted with bar plot with the command:

```
barplot(head(goeth.sorted.freq.list,10), width=100, las=2, col=rainbow(15))
```

Since the picture quality is getting very worse with barplot when it comes to a higher width (more columns), I would like to do exact the same `ggplot2`. But I can't find a solution, since I don´t know how the other solution presented here adapt to my problem. `ggplot2` always give me the answer:

> ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class array

(doesn’t matter, which command I try, all my commands are wrong)

Is there a better way to get `jpegs` or `png` pictures, i supposedly need `ggplot2` only for the `jpegs/pngs` since the plots are just fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use data frames instead of arrays and the "identity" stat instead of the bin and you should be fine, the following example should work:

```
library(ggplot2)
vec <- c(35,24,23,20,16,15,13,12,12,12)
names(vec)<- c("und","der","die","ihr","das","ein","was","es","euch","man")
ggplot(data.frame(names=names(vec), freq=vec), aes(x=names, y=freq))+geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

[image: barplot]

U might see that ggplot per default uses lexographic order in this plot. U can change the order in which the words appear by changing the level of the factor for the x-Aesthetics. So lets say ur vector was already ordered, and the order of the names shall be the same in the plot then u need to do this instead:

```
ggplot(data.frame(names=factor(names(vec), levels=names(vec)), freq=vec), aes(x=names, y=freq))+geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

producing the following plot
[image: ordered barplot]

Comment: Had to convert the vector into arrays of names and numbers: vec<-print(unname(head(text1.sorted.freq.list,50)))  and names(vec)<-names(head(text1.sorted.freq.list,50)). Now the ggplot is working, thank you. But i cannot see any improvement in the quality of the generated picture. Have to investigate a little bit more. Thank you

Comment: I dont rly know what u mean by quality of the graphic, but if the x-Axis-labels are a problem u can rotate them with something like ...+ theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle = -90, hjust = 0)). Or u just want more pixels in ur png, then u might wanna have a look at the height or width option of the png() device.

Comment: I mean the quality of the jpg or png. Perhaps i have to fiddle a little bit with the parameters, but the quality of the generated jpg or png is just as the quality from the barplot command (and that was the reason, why i tried to use an other way with ggplot). But nevertheless, it is now clear, how i have to use plot, with some conversions of my data.